# How to submit an mvc form using javascript while passing controller name and action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to submit an mvc form using JavaScript to my controller and particular action method? I am hoping that if I use JavaScript that the action method will receive the model the form is using.  Normally I would use a submit button in the form but I am not able to make a submit button work within a bootstrap modal popup form.  I have seen the following method to submit a form using JavaScript but it does not specify the action method to be used in the controller:

$("#myForm").submit();

The controller needs to receive the form's view model in a specific action method (i.e. MyAction1) as shown below:

```
        public PartialViewResult MyAction1(ViewModelabc aViewModelabc)
        {
         .....
         return PartialView("_Browse", aViewModelabc);
        }
```

Basically I need to submit the form using JavaScript in a way that it is just like clicking a form submit button that targets a specific action method like the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-backdrop="false" 
data-dismiss="modal" id="id-FindModalSubmitBtn" formaction="MyAction1">
     Load Selected Item</button>
```

------  UPDATE -----

I've added the bootstrap modal popup below which has a submit button at the bottom which is not reaching the designated controller action method specified in the BeginForm and submit button.

```
<div class="modal" id="id-FindModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Purchase Order Lookup</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("PartialViewForBrowseWithModel", "PurchaseOrder", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <div class="row row-spacing ">
                            <div class="form-group row-spacing ">
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.PurchaseOrderIds, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label  LabelStyle1 row-spacing " })
                                <div class=" row-spacing ">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.PurchaseOrderId,
                         new SelectList(Model.PurchaseOrderIds, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select",
                         new
                         {
                             @class = "form-control row-spacing DropDownStyle2 ",
                             @style = "width:100%; height:28px;",
                             @id = "id-DropDownPurchaseOrderId-FindModal"
                         })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PurchaseOrderId, "", new { @class = "text-danger row-spacing " })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-backdrop="false" data-dismiss="modal"
                                    id="id-FindModalSubmitBtn" formaction="PartialViewForBrowseWithModel">
                                Load Selected Purchase Order
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `I am not able to make a submit button work within a bootstrap modal popup form` forms work fine in BS modals, so that's the first problem you should be looking to fix

Comment: `I have seen the following method to submit a form using JavaScript but it does not specify the action method to be used in the controller: $("#myForm").submit();`. That submits the form as normal, and sends it to the location provided in the `action` attribute of the form

Comment: Remove `formaction=` from your button, then it will what you've specified in `@Html.BeginForm`

Comment: Your issues are most likely caused by `formaction="PartialViewForBrowseWithModel"` not including the controller, ie it should be `formaction="PurchaseOrder\PartialViewForBrowseWithModel"` - so use `formaction='@Url.Action("PartialViewForBrowseWithModel", "PurchaseOrder")'` to get the correct path.  If your view is already in "PurchaseOrder" then you can use `formaction='@Url.Action("PartialViewForBrowseWithModel")'` but note the "PurcaseOrder"(controller) is **implied** so will still output `PurchaseOrder\PartialViewForBrowseWithModel` (or whatever is actually required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is, can I submit a view model using JavaScript, calling an MVC controller with that model, then yes, you certainly can do that.

The form can look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "_frmSubmitId", role = "form"})
{
    // Do whatever

    <button type="submit" id="_btnSubmit">Submit</button>
}


<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#_frmSubmitId").submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();    // Stops the default Beginform functionallity

            var formdata = $("#_frmSubmitId").serialize();    // Serializes the form

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("// Method", "// Controller")',
                type:'POST',
                data: formdata,
                success: function(result){
                    // Do whatever
                }
            });
        });
    })

</script>
```

The model which we are serializing is the view model (whatever model is at the top of the view), so this is what the controller method will need to have as it's parameter. So I am guessing in this case, `ViewModelabc` is the view model.

Comment: This bit is confusing: *"The model which we are serializing is the view model"* - you're serializing the *form* (the inputs/selects/etc inside the form).  This may or may not have anything to do with the viewmodel.  This is then converted to the action's parameter(s) using Model Binding - the action's parameter(s) also may or may not have anything to do with the viewmodel.